# Deserialize with an async callback

Tags: ember.js

I'm overriding the deserialize method so I can load an object from the backend corresponding with the id. However, the way I get this object is asynchronous. Deserialize does not wait for my callback and returns automatically.

Example:

```
show: Em.Route.extend({
        route: "/:id",
        deserialize: function(router, post) {
            var postController = router.get('postController ');
            postController.findById(post.id, function(post) {
                return post
            });
        }
```

The call to the backend is made but deserialize returns automatically. Is there a way to work with asynchronous call in deserialize?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Luke Melia did an NYC Ember meetup lightning talk on this very thing, using Promises via jQuery Deferred objects. Basically, Ember detects if you return a Promise (by seeing if the object has a `then` method), and puts the route in a `loading` state (which you have to declare as a sibling of the state with the deserialize). On `ajax.done`, you can resolve the promise, which puts the router fully in the state with the data fully loaded.

With the new router, you're not really supposed to use the support for async transitions that is present in the vanilla statemanager, but you can use the automatic loading states to achieve the same kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have found out, this would work in older versions of ember:

In the enter function of the state/route you can try to load the data. The enter function receives as second argument at transition object which have 2 methods. One is 'async' which tells the transition that it cant continue until the other method 'resume' has bean called.

So in the example:

```
    ...
    enter: function (r, t) {
           t.async();
           r.get('postController').loadResources(t.resume);
    },
    ...
```

Comment: this however seams not to be true for newer version of ember?

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Ember you should use some kind of proxy for the data you load.

```
    {
      PostController: Ember.ObjectController.extend({
          find: function (id) {
              var ajax = Em.$.ajax(); //call the ajax thing
              ajax.done(Em.$.proxy(function (data) {
                  this.set('content', data);
              }, this));
              return this;
          }
      })
      ...
      Router: Em.Router.extend({
          show: Em.Route.extend({
              deserialize: function(router, post) {
                  var postController = router.get('postController');
                  postController.find(post.id);
                  return postController;
              }
          });
      })
    }
```

Comment: Whilst returning a proxy will work, it can cause problems later. Proxies do not forward method calls so you may need to detect if an object is proxy before invoking methods later.

Comment: @Garth In this case its data from a ajax call, so i dont think it has methods.

Comment: The example shown is only very basic. In most cases you would want to turn `data` into an ember model object when the ajax callback is received.