# Ember.js - Asyncronous call in model find() method

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have implemented `find()` and `findAll()` methods on my Property model.  Both methods make asynchronous calls to an API.  `findAll()` is called while connecting the outlets for my home route, and works fine.  `find()` is called by Ember.js while connecting the outlets for my property route.  Note that `find()` is not called when navigating to a property route through actions, but is called when you go directly to the route through the URL.

Here is my router:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        showProperty: Ember.Route.transitionTo('property'),
        home: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home', App.Property.findAll());
            }        
        }),
        property: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/property/:property_id',
            connectOutlets: function(router, property) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('property', property);
            }
        }),
    })
});
```

And here are my `findAll()` and `find()` methods:

```
App.Property.reopenClass({
    find: function(id) {
        var property = {};
        $.getJSON('/api/v1/property/' + id, function(data) {
            property = App.Property.create(data.property);
        });
        return property;
    },
    findAll: function() {
        var properties = [];
        $.getJSON('/api/v1/properties', function(data) {
            data.properties.forEach(function(item) {
                properties.pushObject(App.Property.create(item));
            });
        });
        return properties;
    }
});
```

When I go to a route other than index, for example `http://app.tld/#/property/1`, the route gets rewritten to `http://app.tld/#/property/undefined`.  Nothing is being passed to the `content` property of the Property controller.  How can I make asynchronous calls in the `find()` method?  Unless I am mistaken, asynchronous calls work fine in the `findAll()` method, which is the source of my confusion.

This question is similar to [Deserialize with an async callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244938/deserialize-with-an-async-callback), but I'm using the `find()` method instead of overriding the `deserialize()` method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that setting the `id` property explicitly solves this problem. In your case this would look like this.

```
find: function(id) {
  var user = App.User.create();

  $.getJSON('/api/v1/property/' + id, function(data) {
    user.setProperties(data.user)
  });

  user.set("id",id); // <-- THIS

  return user;
}
```

Once your `user` gets its properties set the view updates as normal. Ember just need the `id` part before in order to update the URL.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want to be doing. I changed the model to User to make things a little clearer.

In the case of `find()`, you return a blank model instance that gets it's properties filled in when the AJAX request comes back. The nice thing about Ember's data-binding is that you can display this model in a view immediately and the view will update when the AJAX request returns and updates the model instance.

In the case of `findAll()`, you return a blank array that gets filled in when the AJAX request comes back. In the same way as `find()`, you can display this list of models (which at first will be blank) in a view and when the AJAX request returns and fills in the array, the view will update.

```
App.User.reopenClass({

  find: function(id) {
    var user = App.User.create();

    $.getJSON('/api/v1/property/' + id, function(data) {
      user.setProperties(data.user)
    });

    return user;
  },

  findAll: function() {
    var userList = [];

    $.getJSON('/api/v1/properties', function(data) {
      var users = data.users.map(function(userData) {
        return App.User.create(userData);
      });
      userList.pushObjects(users);
    });

    return userList;
  }

});
```

Comment: I don't think, it solves the problem. 
I am extending RESTAdapter, and replacing find with
`code var root = this.rootForType(type);
      this.ajax(this.buildURL(root, id), "GET", {
        success: function(json) {
          store.load(type, json);
        }
      }); 
`
When I refresh, My URL changes to 'tool/null/settings' , where null was suppose to be string Id.